# Running Nginx as different user; updating WordPress returns "The update cannot be installed ..." error

Tags: nginx, wordpress

This is my first foray into customizing Nginx, which I have running on a Digital Ocean droplet. My site files are located in `/sites/rob_app`.

- everything is owned by `rob`
- all files are `0644`
- all directories are `0755`

I changed the user that Nginx runs as to `rob` in `nginx.conf`. The site runs, but if I try to update WordPress or any plugins, I get the following error:

```
Unpacking the update…

The update cannot be installed because some files could not be copied. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php

Installation failed.
```

From Nginx error log, it sounds like a file permission issue, but I'm running Nginx as `rob` and my file owner is `rob`:

```
2023/01/27 01:08:51 [error] 11253#11253: *6 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  copy(/sites/rob_app/subdomains/vril/public/wp-admin/includes/update-core.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /sites/rob_app/subdomains/vril/public/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 309" while reading upstream, client: (redacted)), server: vril.robr.app, request: "POST /wp-admin/update-core.php?action=do-core-reinstall HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "(redacted)", referrer: "(redacted)/wp-admin/update-core.php"
```

When I change the file owner for all sites files to `www-data` and change the user that Nginx runs as to `www-data`, then I can successfully update WordPress and plugins, but as `rob`, **I can't add or modify any files within `/sites/` without using `sudo`.**

I'm scratching my head over why r**unning Nginx as `www-data` with `www-data` as the file owner works**, but **running Nginx as `rob` with `rob` as the file owner does not** (even though the file permissions are unchanged between the switch).

My `nginx.conf`:

```
user rob;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off; 

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    # https://sysopstechnix.com/7-tips-for-nginx-performance-tuning/
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 4k;   
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;

    add_header Last-Modified "";    
}
```

Comment: Did you change user and group in your FastCGI config?

Comment: @Freddy Aw man, that was it. Didn't even know that was a thing. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! Please [self-answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to change the user:group for FastCGI; once it matched the user:group for Nginx, everything ran smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

Can use WP-CLI to check and upgrade Wordpress core, plugins, themes.

```
wp core check-update 


wp core update
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).